# How can I replace the filename extension in blender

Tags: blender

I try to replace the extension of filename when blender generate some file.
It's means that lots of file would be generated when user using blender,and the filename extension can be "file.myExtension" instead of "file.blend".
How do I solve my problem?
EX:
file1.blend -> file1.myExtension1
file2.ble -> file2.myExtension2

I build the blender on windows, and I trace the open source of blender.
I think the following class is the key of my problem.
1. file.cc
2. filetype.c
3. fileops.c
4. writefile.c
5. readfile.c
6. wm_files.c
7. BKE_customdata_file.h

But I can't see ".blend" in these code.
I really want to know how to replace file extension.

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a simple change, several places need to be found.

- `source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_files.c:2366` is where `.blend` is added to the save filename.

`BLI_path_extension_ensure(filepath, FILE_MAX, ".blend");`

- `source/blender/blenkernel/BKE_appdir.h` you will find some preference and quit filenames. userprefs can also be found in `release/scripts/startup/bl_operators/userpref.py`

```
#define BLENDER_STARTUP_FILE "startup.blend"
#define BLENDER_USERPREF_FILE "userpref.blend"
#define BLENDER_QUIT_FILE "quit.blend"
```

Depending on your needs you may also want to find the filenames used for temporary crash and auto-save files.

Then there is the open file filters, so that only files with `.blend` show when selecting a file to open.

Comment: Thanks for your help,and I also find the answer today.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer today, and thanks for sambler giving some information.
My blender Version: 2.79

Edit Files:
1. wm_files.c (For save file)

-write_crash_blend()

[image]

-wm_autosave_location()

[image]

-wm_filepath_default()

[image]

-blend_save_check()

[image]

2. readfile.c (For read file)

-BLO_has_bfile_extension()

[image]

Results:

-save file

[image]

-read file

[image]

-success

[image]